# Proper syntax for adding php post data into mySQL string

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have a single field post of the form:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

I am trying to insert `foo` into a small mySql table named `'datatable'` in the database `'mydatabase'` in post.php.

This string works for me to add a data row in my table:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO 'mydatabase'.'datatable' ('data') VALUES (\'testabc\');');
```

So I know my connection string is working.  However, I cannot figure out how to insert the actual post data `($_POST['foo'])` into my table.  I have tried strings such as:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO 'mydatabase'.'datatable' ('data') VALUES (\'' + $_POST['foo'] + '\');');
```

But cannot figure out the correct syntax to make this work.  Can any of you brilliant minds help hint me in the right direction?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses `.` for concatenation, not `+`.

However, you really shouldn't use `mysql_*`.  I highly suggest [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It's simple to use and will protect you from injection (to which you are currently vulnerable).  You may also need to consider that magic quotes is enabled so `stripslashes` on the post data may be appropriate.  `trim`. usually is as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me.  This community is wonderful.  I was apparently walking straight into a world of hurt...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using `+` to concatenate the parts of the query string. In php string concatenation is done using the dot `.`. What you could do is

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `mydatabase`.`datatable` (`data`) VALUES (\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo']) . '\');');
```

but like was mentioned in the comments below you really should be using PDO.

Comment: @eggyal - yes I know and I agree. I'm just trying to help the OP with an answer to his question.

Comment: Thank you both!  Er, as you probably guessed, I am very new at this.  Thank you for scaring me straight before pushing this fix through...  (fantastic XKCD warning btw).